# CSS * selector, how to exclude :hover

Tags: javascript, css

How can i exclude `*` selector from each class with `:hover`?

Or how can i change every `:hover` to style it differently?

Comment: Please include some code you have tried so far.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there are two ways you can try:

First you can use the `:not()` selector and create a rule that apply to every element that has not the hover:

```
*:not(:hover) {
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

However, the `:not()` selector is not supported in IE8 or less, so the second option is to create an unstyled class, and override those properties for that element with that class:

```
.unstyled:hover {
  background-color:none;
  color:#000
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have You Tried: `(:not)` ?

**Examples:**

```
*:not(:hover) { /* here */}
.container:hover img:not(:hover) {/* here */}
```

**Ref:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not

**Tut:** https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/

**Can I use:** http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the [specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) you define. So this is the normal behaviour.

`p:hover` is more specific then `*:hover` so if you hover over `<p>` it will be green.

```css
*:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

p:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello world</p>
```